# Can we prove using intuitionist logic that $\neg \exists r: \forall x: [P(x,r) \iff \neg P(x,x)]$

Tags: intuitionistic-logic

Can we prove using intuitionist logic that $\neg \exists r: \forall x:  [P(x,r) \iff \neg P(x,x)]$ where $P$ is a binary logical predicate?

Comment: Yes, [negation introduction is intuitionistically valid](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1636703/152568), and the formula under $\neg$ leads to contradictory propositions (taking $x=r$) fulfilling its antecedent.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks. I thought intuitionistic logic would not allow the required proof by contradiction since they reject LEM.

Comment: Yes, this is a common loose formulation. They allow proofs by contradiction with *negative* conclusions. But if you derive a contradiction from $¬p$, as is usually done, you can not infer $p$ intuitionistically (double negation is not removable).

Comment: The usual intuitionistic proof of $\lnot(P \leftrightarrow \lnot P)$ is: suppose $P \leftrightarrow \lnot P$.  Then if you suppose $P$, then you also have $\lnot P$, giving a contradiction; by $\lnot I$, this overall implies $\lnot P$.  But then you also have $P$, giving a contradiction; so by $\lnot I$, $\lnot(P \leftrightarrow \lnot P)$.